# Query DynamoDB table using multiple GSI simultaneously

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a DynamoDB to store logs, the table has the columns creation_year, creation_month and state_code, I need to filter by those columns so I created a GSI for each, right now I have the following query for one index and it works fine:

```
let command = new QueryCommand({
    TableName: "my-table",
    IndexName: 'creation_year-index',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":creation_year":  "2023"
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: "creation_year = :creation_year"
  });
```

However now I need to fetch a log from X creation_year and Y creation_month (and later on by state_code as well), how could I build such query combining global secondary indexes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder why did you choose DynamoDB for logs storage. Dynamo is not meant for that. ElasticSearch or MongoDB would be better options IMHO.

Comment: We currently user ElasticSearch in an on-prem server but the plan is to migrate to AWS, however OpenSearch is overkill for what we actually need (more inserts than reads and TTL of 4 years for those logs). I'm exploring an approach but this seems like a deal breaker, I'll have to take a look to RDS.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You can create a hierarchical sort key, but it may not be suitable.

Best approach would be to use the Keyconditionexpression to narrow down the items as much as possible, then use a filter expression to filter the remaining subset of items.

If you only ever want a specific month worth of data for a given year then a simple GSI like this will work

| PK | SK | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023:04 | Status | Some data |

But it's more likely you are searching for a specific log belonging to a single process within a given time period, in that case it's bests to use a timestamp as sort key:

| PK | SK | Status | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LogSourceId | 2023-04-01T20:55:000 | Status | Some data |

Now for a given metric, you can check all of the logs within millisecond granularity. You can further filter on status. However, if you find that your filtering is inefficient, you can also append the status to the sort key.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an aggregated field that have the year and month like this: `{creation_year}_{creation_month}`, and create a GSI for it. For the `state_code` you could use expression filters.

Comment: Thank you, tomorrow I'll take a look at Expression Filters and how to combine it with KeyConditionExpression/ExpressionAttributeValues.